# xhtml anchor link to div, but div has generic id?

Tags: css, xhtml, anchor

If I want to link to a place within the same* page. I've seen that should do like this:

```
<a href="#div-id">Link Text Here</a>
```

But what if I have several divs with the same id? Is there way to distinguish other than using the id of the div?

I generate the xhtml code from Java and to match the generic css file (that will not be generated) I use "generic" divs for some cases. Of course I could generate a dummy div with no style attributes but with a unique id and wrap that one around the area of interest. I'm however curious if it could be done in a better way?

Comment: id's are suppose to be unique.  Use a CSS class for rules that you need to apply to multiple elements.

Comment: True, that sounds kind of obvious when you start to think about it. :-) I'll go for that and do a bit of rework. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id attribute is optional. However according to w3schools if an element has an id attribute then the id value must be unique. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp.

ID Naming rules:

- Must contain at least one character
- Must not contain any space characters In HTML
- all values are case-insensitive

And from what I have learned from experience and html validation it must not start with a number but nobody told me that...

Comment: You answer is a bit misleading.  Elements on a page are not required to have an id.  However, a specific id value should only be assigned to a single element.